# Проверка, разрабатывается ли сейчас приложение. ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть функция в сервисе:

```
    public async Task<ServiceResult> AddPosition(string name)
    {
        ServiceResult result = new ServiceResult();

        if (await _positions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name == name.Trim().ToUpper()) != null)
        {
            result.Message = "Position already exists";
            return result;
        }

        try
        {
            Position newPosition = new Position()
            {
                Name = name.Trim().ToUpper()
            };

            await _positions.AddAsync(newPosition);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            result.Result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Result = false;
            //result.Message = "Database Error";
            result.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Необходимо, чтобы когда приложение разрабатывается, то выводило в результате сообщение возникшего исключения (`result.Message = ex.Message;`), а когда приложение опубликовано, то выводило мой текст ошибки (`result.Message = "Database Error";`). Можно, конечно, передавать статус приложения в функцию как параметр, менять строку сообщения об ошибке перед публикацией, или добавить bool свойство в класс сервиса и указывать статус приложения в конструкторе, но мне кажется это все не очень красиво и должен быть более простой способ.

Нужно это все, чтобы обычный пользователь не видел сообщение исключения, но при разработке программист его видел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте как-то так, должно работать.

```
#if DEBUG
   public const bool DEBUG = true;
#else
   public const bool DEBUG = false;
#endif

public async Task<ServiceResult> AddPosition(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Result = false;
            result.Message = DEBUG ? ex.Message : "Database Error";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: К сожалению, ваше решение не работает https://pp.userapi.com/c836720/v836720140/4aeab/kbGy0q6Tuus.jpg .

Comment: а что не так на скрине? у меня так же. `когда приложение разрабатывается` используем режим `Debug`, когда публикуем используем режим `Release`.

Comment: вы правы, все работает. Я просто подумал что если серым строка стала то она вообще не будет работать. Большое спасибо вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Одна из ключевых особенностей нового ASP.NET Core — встроенная поддержка различных Environment variables. 
Информацию о них может предоставить интерфейс [IHostingEnvironment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment) посредством следующих методов расширения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычно уже инициализированная абстракция `IHostingEnvironment` приходит в конструктор класса `Startup`:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    HostingEnvironment = env; //

}
```

Для того, чтобы в дальнейшем передавать `IHostingEnvironment` между компонентами приложения, необходимо сначала создать в классе `Startup` свойство типа `IHostingEnvironment`:

```
public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }
```

Затем в конструкторе `Startup` инициализируем его значением параметра `env`, как показано в коде выше. Теперь просто регистрируем синглтон-сервис `IHostingEnvironment` в методе `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(t => HostingEnvironment);
}
```

Всё! Теперь можно инжектировать сервис в нужный компонент или контроллер приложения.
Есть два варианта:

1. Инжектировать в конструктор, стандартно, думаю в пояснении это не
   нуждается.
2. Инжектировать напрямую в нужный метод через его параметры. При этом нужно перед внедряемым сервисом обязательно указать атрибут `[FromServices]`. В итоге ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   public async Task<ServiceResult> AddPosition(string name, [FromServices] IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       try
       {
           //
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           result.Result = false;
           result.Message = env.IsDevelopment() ? ex.Message : "Database Error";
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

Подробнее — [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments).